# Como fazer um sistema de login na mesma pagina?

Tags: php, html

**Exemplo:**

A página de `login` e a página do `usuário` quando se está logado e no mesmo `index`, mas não sei como fazer isto.

```html
<!--comeco login
    <html><head></head><body><h1 class="top">PAINEL DE USUÁRIO</h1>
      <ul id="left_menu">
      <table width="266" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td width="66" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">
      <div style="margin-left:10px;">
      <input value="" style="width:90%;" placeholder="digite seu login..." required="" name="login" id="rnewpassword" maxlength="12" type="text" autocomplete="off">
      <input value="" style="width:90%;" placeholder="digite sua senha..." required="" name="password" id="rnewpassword" maxlength="12" type="password" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;"><a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/iNext_rSenha.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="font-size:11px;"><img src="http://www.cabalxnew.com.br/template/images/bullet.png">&nbsp;Perdeu sua senha? clique aqui</a></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;margin-left:10px; margin-top:20px;"><a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/recuperarmail.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="font-size:11px;"><img src="http://www.cabalxnew.com.br/template/images/bullet.png">&nbsp;Recuperar meu email!</a></div>




<input style="float: right; margin-bottom:7px;" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/validar.php', {method: 'post', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(document.logar)}); carregando(); mover();" type="button" value="Logar" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit">


  </td>
</tr><tr>
</tr></tbody></table>
  </ul> 
 
 
</body></html>
final login -->
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
  <h1 class="top">Gerenciamento de Conta</h1>
  <div style="padding-left: 15px;">





    Bem-vindo: <b style="color:#67BEFD;font-weight:normal;">romario</b>.
    <br>Cash: <span id="coins_cash" name="coins_cash">0</span> 
    <img src="template/images/pc.png" style="margin: 0 0 -1px 0" border="0" height="10">
    <br>T-Point: <span id="coins_cash" name="coins_cash">10</span> 
    <img src="template/images/pc2.png" style="margin: 0 0 -1px 0" border="0" height="10">
    <br>Conta está: <span id="coins_cash" name="coins_cash"><font style="color:#8A0808;">Offline</font></span>
    <br>
    <script>
      $j(document).ready(function() {

        getTempo(0);

      });
    </script>
    Tempo de Jogo: <span id="coins_cash" name="coins_cash"><strong class="tempodejogo"></strong></span>
    <br>
    <img src="template/images/sidebar-box-head.png" style="position:absolute; margin-top:-9px; margin-left:-8px;">
    <br>
  </div>
  <ul id="left_menu">
    <li>
      <p>
        <img src="template/images/bullet.png"><span id="nationwarx3"></span> 
        <a onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/USER/p-user.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="cursor:pointer;">Painel do usuario</a>
      </p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <p>
        <img src="template/images/bullet.png"><span id="nationwarx3"></span> 
        <a onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/USER/p-admin.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="cursor:pointer;">Painel do administrador</a>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>
        <img src="template/images/bullet.png"><span id="nationwarx3"></span> 
        <a onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/USER/p-mod.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="cursor:pointer;">Painel do Moderador</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>



  <div class="natal-chapeu-buttom-deslogar"></div>
  <input style="float: right; margin-right:5px;" value="Deslogar" tabindex="3" name="login_out" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/validar.php?sair=sair', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); carregando(); mover();" type="button">
  <div style="height:2px;"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: não entendi muito bem qual é sua dúvida, o que você não consegue fazer especificamente? Você não consegue mostrar uma pagina diferente para a situação de estar logado ou não estar, mas na mesma pagina?

Comment: pelo que entendi vc quer mostrar a interface de login ou a interface do usuário no mesmo index? se sim você pode usar o angularjs ou o jquery...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom pelo que entendi, a sua dúvida é como fazer na mesma página uma página diferente para a situação de estar logado e outra quando não está.
Primeiro comece com a verificação se o usuário está ou não logado. Como você não deu um exemplo do php, vai uma exemplificação aqui.

```
<?php 
//vefificação se o usuario esta logado ou não
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'] && !empty($_SESSION['usuario'])){

//aqui dentro o usuário esta logado

}
else{

//aqui dentro o usuário não esta logado

}
?>
```

E aqui esta quase pronto. Falta fazer o que realmente importa, exibir a parte diferente. Ou você pode optar por separar em arquivos como: `login.php` e `painel.php` dar um include, assim:

```
    <?php 
//vefificação se o usuario esta logado ou não
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'] && !empty($_SESSION['usuario'])){

//aqui dentro o usuário esta logado
include('painel.php');
}
else{

//aqui dentro o usuário não esta logado
include('login.php');
}
?>
```

Ou você pode fazer de maneira direta, abrindo e fechando o php e colocando no meio o html, prefiro em arquivos separados porque deixa mais fácil de se compreender e tal, mas com o seu exemplo ficaria assim.

```
    <?php 
//vefificação se o usuario esta logado ou não
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'] && !empty($_SESSION['usuario'])){

//aqui dentro o usuário esta logado
?>
    <html>
<head></head>

<body>
  <h1 class="top">Gerenciamento de Conta</h1>
  <div style="padding-left: 15px;">





    Bem-vindo: <b style="color:#67BEFD;font-weight:normal;">romario</b>.
    <br>Cash: <span id="coins_cash" name="coins_cash">0</span> 
    <img src="template/images/pc.png" style="margin: 0 0 -1px 0" border="0" height="10">
    <br>T-Point: <span id="coins_cash" name="coins_cash">10</span> 
    <img src="template/images/pc2.png" style="margin: 0 0 -1px 0" border="0" height="10">
    <br>Conta está: <span id="coins_cash" name="coins_cash"><font style="color:#8A0808;">Offline</font></span>
    <br>
    <script>
      $j(document).ready(function() {

        getTempo(0);

      });
    </script>
    Tempo de Jogo: <span id="coins_cash" name="coins_cash"><strong class="tempodejogo"></strong></span>
    <br>
    <img src="template/images/sidebar-box-head.png" style="position:absolute; margin-top:-9px; margin-left:-8px;">
    <br>
  </div>
  <ul id="left_menu">
    <li>
      <p>
        <img src="template/images/bullet.png"><span id="nationwarx3"></span> 
        <a onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/USER/p-user.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="cursor:pointer;">Painel do usuario</a>
      </p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <p>
        <img src="template/images/bullet.png"><span id="nationwarx3"></span> 
        <a onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/USER/p-admin.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="cursor:pointer;">Painel do administrador</a>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>
        <img src="template/images/bullet.png"><span id="nationwarx3"></span> 
        <a onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/USER/p-mod.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="cursor:pointer;">Painel do Moderador</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>



  <div class="natal-chapeu-buttom-deslogar"></div>
  <input style="float: right; margin-right:5px;" value="Deslogar" tabindex="3" name="login_out" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/validar.php?sair=sair', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); carregando(); mover();" type="button">
  <div style="height:2px;"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>

</html>

<?php
}
else{
//aqui dentro o usuário não esta logado
?>
    <html><head></head><body><h1 class="top">PAINEL DE USUÁRIO</h1>
      <ul id="left_menu">
      <table width="266" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td width="66" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">
      <div style="margin-left:10px;">
      <input value="" style="width:90%;" placeholder="digite seu login..." required="" name="login" id="rnewpassword" maxlength="12" type="text" autocomplete="off">
      <input value="" style="width:90%;" placeholder="digite sua senha..." required="" name="password" id="rnewpassword" maxlength="12" type="password" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;"><a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/iNext_rSenha.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="font-size:11px;"><img src="http://www.cabalxnew.com.br/template/images/bullet.png">&nbsp;Perdeu sua senha? clique aqui</a></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;margin-left:10px; margin-top:20px;"><a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/recuperarmail.php', {method: 'get', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); esperar('container'); carregando(); mover();" style="font-size:11px;"><img src="http://www.cabalxnew.com.br/template/images/bullet.png">&nbsp;Recuperar meu email!</a></div>




<input style="float: right; margin-bottom:7px;" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'template/php/validar.php', {method: 'post', asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(document.logar)}); carregando(); mover();" type="button" value="Logar" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit">


  </td>
</tr><tr>
</tr></tbody></table>
  </ul> 


</body></html>


<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: opa estou com esse pequeno erro sabe me informar oque e ?
Erro: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Nenhuma conex�o p�de ser feita porque a m�quina de destino as recusou ativamente.

Comment: Sua conexão com o banco esta tudo certo?

Comment: @RooOliveira nesse caso já é outra dúvida. Sugiro que utilize o site para fazer outra pergunta. Se essa resposta resolveu ao que foi perguntando, sugiro-lhe que marque-a como útil.